# How do I start runBoot before starting the Cypress Tests in Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, cypress

> I want a spring boot  by using bootRun task Gradle. When spring boot is up running should Gradle run the Cypress API test
>   I have the following build.gradle

```
plugins { id 'base'}
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/integration-test.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/functional-test.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/build.gradle"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    localGroovy()
    testCompile ('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.7')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5')
    testImplementation gradleTestKit()

}


 allprojects {
   task printInfo {
      doLast {
         println "This is ${project.name}"
      }
    }   
}

task systemtestDevEnv (type: Exec){ 
        workingDir 'frontend' 
        commandLine 'npm test'
        commandLine 'npm start'

        workingDir 'functionalsystemtest' 
        commandLine 'npm run cypress:run'
    }
    systemtestDevEnv.dependsOn 'backend:runWebServer'

task functionalapitest (type: Exec) {  
    workingDir 'funcionalapitest'
    commandLine 'npm run cypress:run' 

}
 functionalapitest.dependsOn 'backend:runWebServer'
```

> The in the project is the directory stucture is
>
> JavaProject
>    -- fuctionalsystemtest
>    -- functionalapitest
>    -- backend
>    -- frontend
>    -- buildSrc
>   When I exeute gradle functionalapitest is the bootRun been exeuted but the exeution do not exeut the next steps 
>   workingDir 'funcionalapitest'
>   commandLine 'npm run cypress:run' 
>   How sould I spesifie the ask functionalapitest so that after the spring boot prosess is up an running then the cypresse test is exeuted?
>
> Task :backend:bootRun

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-25 13:48:20.457  INFO 59589 --- [           main] c.s.r.R.RestfulWebServiceApplication     : Starting RestfulWebServiceApplication on Steins-MacBook-Air.local with PID 59589 (/Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/JavaProject/backend/build/classes/java/main started by steinkorsveien in /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/JavaProject/backend)
2019-07-25 13:48:20.469  INFO 59589 --- [           main] c.s.r.R.RestfulWebServiceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-25 13:48:23.388  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-25 13:48:23.466  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-25 13:48:23.467  INFO 59589 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-07-25 13:48:23.798  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-25 13:48:23.799  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3188 ms
2019-07-25 13:48:24.356  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-07-25 13:48:24.977  INFO 59589 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-07-25 13:48:24.989  INFO 59589 --- [           main] c.s.r.R.RestfulWebServiceApplication     : Started RestfulWebServiceApplication in 6.301 seconds (JVM running for 7.844)
<=======------> 60% EXECUTING [20s]

Comment: You should run your spring boot app in a docker container and run your cypress tests against the running container.  Gradle has good integration with Docker.  Also, no need to run bootrun, just run java -jar in the container.